# Maximizing $2\text{Tr}(AX) - \|AX\|_F^2$ for p.s.d X?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

For a positive semi-definite $A$, I need to find positive semi-definite $X$ which maximizes the following

$$2\text{Tr}(AX) - \|AX\|_F^2$$

1. Is there a geometric or statistical interpretation of this quantity?
2. I suspect it's maximized by $X=A^\dagger$, the pseudo-inverse, is there an easy way of showing this?

Motivation: this [gives](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41726/what-makes-a-good-preconditioner-when-only-a-few-approximate-iterations-are-need) improvement in error norm squared after 1 step of least squares gradient descent to solve $Aw=b$ with preconditioner $X$

Comment: Notice that it is equivalent to maximise $Tr(2XA - XX^TA^TA)$

Comment: And yea, the pseudoinverse is indeed the maximiser. Notice that you can always suppose $A$ diagonal. Once you have that, it is easy to conclude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\langle X,Y \rangle_F = tr(X^TY)$ be the Frobenius inner product. Then the expression you are trying to maximize is $2\langle AX, I \rangle_F - \langle AX, AX\rangle_F$, but maximizing that is equivalent to minimizing $\langle AX, AX\rangle_F-2 \langle AX, I \rangle_F $, which is turn equivalent to minimizing $\langle AX, AX\rangle_F-2\langle AX, I \rangle_F +\langle I, I \rangle_F=\| AX-I\|^2_F.$

This gives a sort of geometric interpretation of what you are looking for: you are minimizing a distance between a family of matrices and the identity matrix.

By using the definition of the Frobenius norm together with the cyclic shift property of trace, one can show that $\|UZU^T\|_F^2=\|Z\|_F^2$ for any orthogonal matrix $U$, and so one if $A=UDU^T$ is the orthogonal diagonalization of $A$, then $\|AX-I\|_F^2=\|DY-I\|^2_F$ where $UYU^T=X$.

In the diagonal case, it is a straight forward calculation to show that the pseudoinverse a the minimizer (the bottom $\dim \ker D$ rows can be arbitrary, giving some flexibility in the solution), and so the pseudoinverse is a minimizer in general.

Comment: At this point, one may perform the minimization in the basis of eigenvectors of $A$, in which case the objective function becomes $$||DX - I||^2_F$$ for diagonal $D$. Now, $DX$ is just scaling the rows of $X$ by the diagonal entries of $D$. This means the optimal $X$ must be diagonal: if $X$ had off-diagonal entries, one could make the objective function smaller by replacing those off-diagonal entries by zero. And now that we know $X$ is diagonal in the eigenvector basis of $A$, one can see the pseudoinverse is optimal.

Comment: The last two paragraphs seem unnecessary. After the first paragraph, one already sees that $X=A^+I=A^+$ is a global optimiser in the *unconstrained* problem. However, since $A^+$ is PSD when $A$ is PSD, $X=A^+$ is a global optimiser in the original constrained problem too.